# Word 2007 vba, directly select field by name attribute of code property?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to have vba select a field in a word doc using the NAME attribute of the field  CODE property? maybe using a pseudo selector?

background:
i have 8 fields (DOCPROPERTY Name_First, Name_Last, etc) in my document in 4 places (total 32 items)

instead of looping through the entire collection of fields, I want to be able to return a collection of fields that match Name_First, and then make changes,InsertAfter, etc, then call the update method on those fields only. Updating all fields is causing a noticeable delay on each form field when exited to the next field.

The MSDN documentation only shows examples using ordinal index numbers, which isn't very helpful in my real world. If someone changes the ordinal position of a field, DonkeyKong!

Comment: Looping seems to be the only way. You could divide your document into sections to limit searching to those fields which are in appropriate section- it's just idea.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My doc is only 1 page, but contains many fields, so the section divide would not really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bookmark can be referenced by name. If you want to update say 4 fields to reflect Name_First, you could place bookmarks on all 4 fields with names like "Name_First_1", "Name_First_2" etc. Then update the fields like:

```
For i = 1 To 4
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name_First_" & i).Range.Fields(1).Update
Next
```

In your words: the bookmarked range is the pseudo selector. The field to update is always the first field in the referenced range.

Comment: Interesting thinking outside the box! Previously I only thought of bookmarks as shortcuts to locations i a document, but now I realize they can be used to select a range. This is also a plus, because I was looking for a way to insert a line break, and it doesn't work with a field, but it works with an enclosing bookmark using InsertBefore. So Thanks!